# Associating object with cells on a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to associate Ellipse2D objects with a cell on a JTable.  Specifically if the user clicks on one Ellipse2D then it would highlight a cell on the JTable and accept input.  I need to do this in a way that allows the user to associate a string with each Ellipse.

Is what I am trying to do possible and if so how can I do this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SelfContainedExample extends JPanel {
    private List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
    }

    public SelfContainedExample()
    {
        //Circle of Radios
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(250, 100, 20, 20));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(160, 100, 20, 20));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(70, 100, 20, 20));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(70, 160, 20, 20));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(160, 160, 20, 20));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(250, 160, 20, 20));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        shapes.forEach(g2d::fill);

        g2d.dispose();
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        Object[][] data = {{"1_1", "1_2", "1_3"},
                           {"2_1", "2_2", "2_3"}};

        Object[] columnNames = {"1", "2", "3"};
        JTable jtable = new JTable(data, columnNames);

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(new SelfContainedExample(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(jtable, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( false );
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setContentPane( panel );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well maybe you start by creating a `HashMap` where the key is the ellipse and the value is a Point, where the Point would represent the row/column of the ellipse in the table.

```
//shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(250, 100, 20, 20));
Ellipse2D.Double ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(...);
shapes.add(ellipse);
shapesMap.put(ellipse, new Point(0, 0);
```

> the user clicks on one Ellipse2D then it would highlight a cell on the JTable and accept input.

So then you need to add a MouseListener to your panel and handle the mousePressed() event. The code would need to iterate through the List to find the ellipse that contains the point. Then you can start editing on the cell. Maybe something like:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    for (Ellipse2D.Double ellipse: shapes)
    {
        if (ellipse.contains(e.getPoint())
        {
            table.requestFocusInWindow();
            Point p = shapesMap.get(ellipse);
            table.editCellAt(p.x, p.y);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```